# how the monotonicity of $\frac{1}{(logn)^n}$ ,with induction or an other way??

Tags: calculus

Could you tell me how to show the monotonicity of $\frac{1}{(logn)^n}$ ? With induction or with an other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us define $a_{n}=\frac{1}{(log(n))^{n}}$

$log(n+1) > log(n)$ for all natural numbers $n$ as the function  $f(x)=log(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Therefore we have $(log(n+1))^{n+1} > (log(n+1))^{n} > (log(n))^{n}$, as clearly $n+1>n$.

Thus $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(log(n+1))^{n+1}} < \frac{1}{(log(n))^{n}} = a_{n}$, and we have $a_{n}$ is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: And which is the limit of this sequence??

Comment: The limit is zero: we can see the sequence $(log n)^{n}$ tends to infinity and is positive for large n, so $\frac{1}{(log n)^{n}}$ is null.

Comment: And how can I show that the sequence $(logn)^{n} $ tends to infinity?

Comment: The sequence is strictly increasing, and is not bounded above, so must tend to infinity

Answer (score 1):

$\frac 1{(\log n)^n}=\exp(-n\log\log n)$ and $n\mapsto n\log \log n$ is increasing.